# How do I select rows where elements of group have the same value?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table like this:

```
 prop1 | prop2
 aaa   | xxx
 aaa   | xxx
 bbb   | yyy
 bbb   | !yyy
 ccc   | zzz
 ccc   | zzz
 ddd   | !kkk
 ddd   | kkk
```

and I want to be like:

```
 prop1 | prop2
 bbb   | yyy
 bbb   | !yyy
 ddd   | !kkk
 ddd   | kkk
```

How do I do in SQL (firebird)?

Comment: You say firebird, but tag <firebase>.

Comment: Do you mean **don't** have the same value??

Comment: Please explain the logic of this selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want result of a select from the table to look like is written in your example, this may be the query:

```
select * from t t1 where exists
  (select * from t t2
    where t1.prop1 = t2.prop1 and t1.prop2 <> t2.prop2)
```

If you want (as topic say) select groups where all rows have the same values then the query is like this:

```
select prop1, MAX(prop2) from t
  group by prop1 having MAX(prop2) = MIN(prop2)
```

If you want your table after a query to look like in your example (i.e. delete groups that you would get from the query above) then it is

```
execute block as
declare p varchar(100);
begin
  for select prop1 from t
    group by prop1 having MAX(prop2) = MIN(prop2)
    into :p do
  begin
    delete from t where prop1 = p;
  end
end
```

Comment: `exists` often is not best choice for Firebird and Interbase engines.  SELECT + GROUP BY + HAVING would be better. That is classic query taught at schools :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The "exists" is done by nested loop. join + group by is done by nested loop + sort. It can be better choice only under very special circumstances. And in this case you cannot avoid join because the author wants all records in groups.

Comment: Oh, okay... You just found yet another interpretation of the topic-starter's very ambiguous request...  But why join would require nested loop? it would be just merging two pre-sorted streams, similarly to streaming-sort's 2nd step. Frankly, when i initally read "I want to be like" and so the output i was sure TS wants to *delete* repeating rows, i still do not totally srtike it out :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The Indeed, I got confused by "select" in topic. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: in case of delete and assuming Firebird 3+ one can use `merge` statement with any of your `select`s. Personally i assumed he just wanted to filter in (or filter out) repeating rows, so `select * from t group by prop1, prop2 having count(*) = 1` (or `... > 1`)

Comment: And in FB2 i suspect your delete would not work: remember that gotcha about `insert into T select * from T` ?

Comment: "group by" materializes result set. Subquery wouldn't work indeed. @Arioch'The